# I need that when the articles are added, the block will expand

Tags: html, css, jinja2

I have a block in which there is a search and the best article for the week to me when I add them for some reason they exit the block and I need the block to expand itself
[image]

```
    <div  class="col-lg-1 col-md-1"></div>
    <div style="background-color:white; height: 470px ; widht: 100% ;  " class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 container">




        <h1>Поиск по Программам</h1>
        <form style="display: flex;" action="{% url 'post_searchProgramm' %}" method="get">
            <input  style=" height:30px; width:300px; border: 3px solid #4242A3; border-radius: 15px ; " type="text" name="searchProggram" value=""> <br>
            <br>
            <input style=" margin-left:30px; height: 30px ; width:100px; border-radius: 30px ; background-color: #8383D0   ;  border: 3px solid #4242A3; " type="submit" value="Найти">

        </form>


        <h1 align="middle" style="border-top:3px solid #000047 ;" >Возможно Это То Что Вам Нужно</h1>
        <div style="border-top:3px solid #000047 ; ">

        {% for top in articles_top %}



        <a href="{% url 'article_detail' top.pk %}"> <h3 onmouseover="this.style.color='#319CD5';" onmouseout="this.style.color='#333';" id="TopArticleHover"  style="  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color:#333; "> {{ top.title }} </h3> </a>

        {%  endfor %}


    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `<div style="background-color:white; height: 470px ; widht: 100% ;  " class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 container">` on line 2 in your code.

Change the `height: 470px ;` to `min-height: 470px; height: auto;`. This should fix your problem.

**Explanation:**
Your current problem is that your block stays at 470px so when you add text and its bigger then 470px the block stays the same. `Height: auto;` makes is so the block height expands with the content thats in it. The `min-height: 470px;` will make it so the box stays at a min-height of 470 pixels even if there is no content in it.